# Emulate Nextcloud Box Ubuntu server with KVM on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, raspberrypi, arm, nextcloud

I am trying to test the [installation images](https://download.nextcloud.com/server/images/) provided by Nextcloud before [flashing them](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Flashing-an-image) on my Raspberry Pi. The images are for the Nextcloud Box - which I have but I want to test before flashing them and destroying a [partially working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891998/nextcloud-box-raspberry-pi-stuck-on-old-kernel) system.

I tried both Ubuntu Core and Ubuntu Server Raspberry Pi 2 images and on both of them I am getting the error:

> No bootable device.

I am using a fully upgraded Ubuntu with the following packages:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
$ uname -r
4.10.0-28-generic
$ apt-cache policy qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils virt-manager cpu-checker
qemu-kvm:
  Installed: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14
  Candidate: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libvirt-bin:
  Installed: 1.3.1-1ubuntu10.11
  Candidate: 1.3.1-1ubuntu10.11
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.1-1ubuntu10.11 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.1-1ubuntu10 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
ubuntu-vm-builder:
  Installed: 0.12.4+bzr494-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.12.4+bzr494-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.12.4+bzr494-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
bridge-utils:
  Installed: 1.5-9ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.5-9ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.5-9ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
virt-manager:
  Installed: 1:1.3.2-3ubuntu1.16.04.3
  Candidate: 1:1.3.2-3ubuntu1.16.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.3.2-3ubuntu1.16.04.3 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.3.2-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
cpu-checker:
  Installed: 0.7-0ubuntu7
  Candidate: 0.7-0ubuntu7
  Version table:
 *** 0.7-0ubuntu7 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I am using the gui through virt-manager (because I am still learning and am not familiar with proper command line setup).

I am using the .img files to start the VM's.

I am thinking that either the images are wrong or kvm needs some info to recognise the arm architecture but it could be something else. I tried through the options to specify the client cpu architecture but couldn't find arm as an option.

**Update:**

I had the same problem after downloading the image for [Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 for Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/). So it may not be the images, but how I am using the virtualiser.